# Worauf kann sich ein Relativsatz beziehen, wenn er auf eine Apposition mit „darunter“ folgt?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, relative-clause

> (a) London beherbergt viele Sehenswürdigkeiten, darunter Weltklassemuseen, die jedes Jahr von Millionen Touristen besichtigt werden.
>
> (b) London beherbergt viele Sehenswürdigkeiten – darunter Weltklassemuseen –, die jedes Jahr von Millionen Touristen besichtigt werden.

Kann sich „die jedes Jahr …“ auf *viele Sehenswürdigkeiten* oder *Weltklassemuseen* beziehen, oder ist beides möglich?

Macht es einen Unterschied, ob man Kommata (wie in a) oder Gedankenstriche (wie in b) benutzt?

Comment: @chirlu Warum sollte es *Weltklassemuseen* und nicht *weltklasse Museen* heißen?

Comment: _Klasse_ wird manchmal als eine Art Adjektiv verwendet (_Sie hat das klasse gemacht, einen klasse Vortrag gehalten_), was schon als stark umgangssprachlich empfunden wird. Mit _Weltklasse_ geht das nicht. _Weltklassemuseum_ ist ein zusammengesetztes Substantiv.

Comment: In Österreich würde man sagen ***'Sie hat einen klassen (tollen) Vortrag gehalten'*** oder *'No hearst,  du bist mar oba a klasser Freund'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grundsätzlich kann es sich auf beides beziehen. Nur bei der Schreibung mit Gedankenstrich ist der Bezug eindeutig, weil die Gedankenstriche erkennbar machen, wo der Einschub endet:

> London beherbergt **viele Sehenswürdigkeiten** – darunter Weltklassemuseen –, **die** jedes Jahr von Millionen Touristen besichtigt werden.
>
> London beherbergt viele Sehenswürdigkeiten – darunter **Weltklassemuseen**, **die** jedes Jahr von Millionen Touristen besichtigt werden.

In der Praxis werden Gedankenstriche allerdings sehr oft falsch verwendet, auch von ausgebildeten Schreibern (Journalisten). Ich würde mich daher bei der Interpretation nicht allzu sehr auf sie verlassen.